# Adding values to placeholder using checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Basically I have 4 checkbox elements in my form and a text field up top. The `text field` has a `placeholder` with a `product name` — `product price` format. Each checkbox has a product name and product price as well, and I want to use javascript to change the placeholder value once a checkbox is checked. The issue is that the product price should be a SUM of default placeholder base price and the product price of the checkbox that was checked. The first part of the placeholder should change from product name to product name + product name.

So far I have only been able to use javascript to change the value of the placeholder entirely, which would work if I had only one checkbox, but I have 4 so it doesn't.

In a perfect world the `placeholder` should display `Basic Package + Video + Picture + Tour + Emergency — €30` when all checkboxes are checked, and `Basic Package + Picture + Tour — €20` when only `Option2` and `Option3` are checked. And so on, and so on.

Here is a simplified code of what I am trying to achieve (note: only Video works in my code):

```js
$('.Option1').on('change', function(e) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked') === true) {
        $('.PriceInput').attr('placeholder', 'Basic Package + Video — €15');
      } else $('.PriceInput').attr('placeholder', 'Basic Package — €10');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ajax-contact-basic" method="post" action="mailer-basic.php">
  <div class="field">
    <input class="form-control PriceInput" type="text" name="basicpackage" id="basicpackage" placeholder="Basic Package — €10" disabled />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option1" type="checkbox" id="videobasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Video">
    <label for="videobasic">Video — €5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option2" type="checkbox" id="picturebasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Picture">
    <label for="picturebasic">Picture — €5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option3" type="checkbox" id="tourbasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Tour">
    <label for="tourbasic">Tour — €5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option4" type="checkbox" id="emergencybasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Emergency">
    <label for="emergencybasic">Emergency — €5</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you need a multi-insert?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I am not entirely sure what you mean by that, could you elaborate? When I googled I stumbled upon SQL query, but I don't work with a database. The data from this form is sent using a PHP mailer.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I guess that could have worked as well, indeed. However someone already commented a solution that works more smoothly with my current situation. Thank you for looking out though!

Comment: Well, if you don't need any more help, then have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the number from each `class="Option"`

then you can do something like this:

```
$('.Option').on('change', function(e) {
  var s = "";
  var p = 10;
  $('.Option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') === true) {
      s += " + " + $(this).val();
      var tempP = +$(this).next().text().split('€')[1];
      p = p + tempP;
    }
  }); 
  $('.PriceInput').attr('placeholder', 'Basic Package' + s + ' — €' + p);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.Option').on('change', function(e) {
  var s = "";
  var p = 10;
  $('.Option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') === true) {
      s += " + " + $(this).val();
      var tempP = +$(this).next().text().split('€')[1];
      p = p + tempP;
    }
  }); 
  $('.PriceInput').attr('placeholder', 'Basic Package' + s + ' — €' + p);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ajax-contact-basic" method="post" action="mailer-basic.php">
  <div class="field">
    <input class="form-control PriceInput" type="text" name="basicpackage" id="basicpackage" placeholder="Basic Package — €10" disabled />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option" type="checkbox" id="videobasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Video">
    <label for="videobasic">Video — €5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option" type="checkbox" id="picturebasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Picture">
    <label for="picturebasic">Picture — €5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option" type="checkbox" id="tourbasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Tour">
    <label for="tourbasic">Tour — €5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="Option" type="checkbox" id="emergencybasic" name="optiesbasic[]" value="Emergency">
    <label for="emergencybasic">Emergency — €5</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks! One question: where do I change the price value for the checkbox? The 5 was an example for this snipper to simplify it.

Comment: And also, for some reason it doesn't work with my code while it works completely fine in that snippet you provided. Is there something I need to be wary of when it comes to complicating the simplified version above?

Comment: I actually figured it out already! Thanks a lot, marked as solution!